# I need a helping hand on my project with a binary converter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a binary converter who translate decimals into binary code, and the program also can turn binary code into decimals.

My problem is i want a whole Ip address into binary code.  Right now i can only write decimals like
172 and get the binary code 10101100, but i cant write whole ip adresss in my program. And the same problem is for my binary code, i can only write 10101100 and get the number 172.

Can you help me?

How do i split up the ip up in 4 Or something can you :)

Its made with javascript html and css in visual studio code, you can test it on Codepen.io

```
Javascript:
//Initial References
let decInp = document.getElementById("dec-inp");
let binInp = document.getElementById("bin-inp");
let errorMsg = document.getElementById("error-msg");

//Convert decimal to binary when user inputs in the decimal field
decInp.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let decValue = parseInt(decInp.value);
  //Converts the decimal value to binary
  binInp.value = decValue.toString(2);
});

//Convert binary to decimal when user inputs in the binary field
binInp.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let binValue = binInp.value;
//If the binary number is valid convert it to decimal
  if (binValidator(binValue)) {
    decInp.value = parseInt(binValue, 2);
    errorMsg.textContent = "";
  }
  //Else display an error message
  else {
    errorMsg.textContent = "Wrong binary code";
  }
  //Function to check if the binary number is valid i.e it does not contain any number other than 0 and 1
  function binValidator(num) {
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (num[i] != "0" && num[i] != "1") {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Binary Converter</title>
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Binary Converter</h2>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <label for="dec-inp">Decimal:</label>
          <input type="number" id="dec-inp" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <label for="bin-inp">Binary:</label>
          <input type="number" id="bin-inp" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <p id="error-msg"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.container {
  background-color: #06f7ff;
  width: 30vmin;
  max-width: 38em;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! I'd approach this by calling the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method on the string to separate the IP Address [into its four octets](https://zsrobinson.com/posts/ip-addresses-for-the-average-person/).

```js
const ipAddressDecimal = "192.168.1.100";
const octetsDecimal = ipAddressDecimal.split(".");
const octetsBinary = octetsDecimal.map((octet) => {
  return parseInt(octet).toString(2);
});
const ipAddressBinary = octetsBinary.join(".");
```